# Can i use an lgpl v3 licensed library in disclosed source code game project

Tags: lgpl

I use an library called Toemsel.Network which makes networking job more easier, but its licensed under lgpl v3 which says make your source code open. I use dynamic linking for using library. Downloading package on nuget.
Can i bypass lgpl problem by downloading dll of library from external site on setup program and automatically place to game folder ?

Answer (score 2):

The LGPL license requires that the library and modifications to the library are made public.

If you dynamically link to the library, then your game can remain closed source, even if you distribute the library in the same package. You just have to make sure that users of your game can replace the Toemsel.Network library with a different, compatible, version.